# Separate permissions for records in a table in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Let's suppose I have different users in my Django project and a model such that each record belongs to a certain user. The users are supposed to have an access to Admin panel.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Is there a standard way in Django to make any user list, create and edit ONLY HIS instances of MyModel in Admin panel, hiding the ones created by other users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override queryset for your model admin. like this:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.filter(user=request.user)
        return qs
```

This will filter out instances based on the user they belong to.

Comment: What if a user tries to edit an instance of another user, inserting id in URL directly like this: http://my.proj/admin/myapp/mymodel/4168198/change/ ? I think, there should be a check to visit this page and to save the model. Could you please, improve your answer?

Comment: Let me verify it please.

Comment: @Fomalhaut No other user can not access any instance like this. He will get error. Because method for getting object also gets its queryset from `get_queryset` (which is overridden).

Comment: Thank you for checking this issue.